# 75% probability in Java

Tags: java, probability

How would I go about implementing a 3/4 or 75% probability using this format in java?

```
Random rand = new Random();
boolean val = rand.nextInt(25)==0;
```

Comment: I think that would be nextInt(4).

Comment: it has to be nextInt(4), that returns 0 with 25% chance, 1 with 25% chance, 2 with 25% chance, 3 with 25% chance. Then check that the value is one of three of those or that it is not one of those.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm not sure why you're getting so many downvotes; this seems to me like a pretty clear question, and you've already received a few answers. Perhaps the downvoters will explain themselves.

Comment: @ChristianConkle I guess they have downvoted due to the lack of research effort. Or maybe because he "borrowed" his code from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8183840/probability-in-java#8183867) without saying so or with trying to understand that code and changing it accordingly. But I'm just guessing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this,

```
Random rand = new Random();
int val = rand.nextInt(4) + 1;
if (val == 1) { // <-- 1/4 of the time.
} else { // <-- 3/4 of the time.
}
```

[`Random.nextInt(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) returns *Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive)*. So, to 0-4 (exclusive) is (0-3) and if you then add 1 the result is the range (1-4).

You might also use [`Random.nextDouble()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextDouble%28%29) like,

```
if (rand.nextDouble() < 0.75) { // <-- 75% of the time.
}
```

Answer (score 6):

A simple-minded way to do it that is good for any integer percent is:

```
boolean val = rand.nextInt(100) < 75;
```

Comment: I'd might be wrong, but shouldn't this be `(rand.nextInt(100) + 1) < 75;`? The range from `0-99` might change the 75% chance a bit.

Comment: @Tom - What if you want 1%?  Or 100%?  Think about it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
rand.nextInt(4) < 3
```

Comment: So he has a `0%` chance? Edit: isn't this just 25%? Wouldn't `rand.nextInt(4) < 3` make more sense?

Comment: This is almost correct. But it is 25% chance, not 75% chance. You should make it != 0.

Answer (score 1):

The following is also valid and somewhat intuitive since many people share the notion of probability as being a value between 0 and 1:

```
Math.random() < 0.75
```

Of course, this is the same as

```
Random rand = new Random();
rand.nextDouble() < 0.75
```

which has been mentioned in the accepted answer.

One important point to note though is that the latter is more efficient than the former. Pete provides an [explanation](https://community.oracle.com/message/6596485#thread-message-6596485) of why this the case on Oracle's community forum.