# Fill 2D Array With Some Probability?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a 4x4 2D array which I need to fill with 1's randomly with probability p (from 0.1 to 1.0), or 0 otherwise. I also need to throw an exception if some nonsense value of p is entered e.g. 0 or -1, how can I do this? Thanks!

```
public GameState(double p) throws Exception 
{
    int[][] grid = new int[4][4];
    Random r = new Random().nextDouble();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            if (r <= p)
            {
                //grid[i][j] = ;
            }
            else
            {
                //grid[i][j] = ;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [How to throw exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/throwing.html)

Comment: You need a random value `r` in range `<0; 1>`. Then you can just check if `r <= p` as you do. If `p = 0.1` then this condition will evaluate to true once every 10 times (on average), if `p = 1` then the condition is always true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can see here how to implement Random (which will solve your probability question):
[Probability in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8183840/probability-in-java)

about the exception - In the beginning of the method, just write something like

```
if (p <0 || p >1) {
    throw new Exception()
}
```