# How to create a switch statement with cases based on exponential probability?

Tags: java, switch-statement, probability

So I want to create a switch statement with each case having a different probability of being picked.

case 1 needs to be:

2 times as likely to occur as case 2

4 times as likely to occur as case 3

16 times as likely to occur as case 4

256 times more likely to occur as case 5

How would i go about creating these cases in java?

Comment: Why a switch? An `if` seems like it would make a lot more sense here.

Comment: there is already a thread on this topic.. [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8183840/probability-in-java) Hope it'll help you.

Comment: I just tend to use switch statements for these types of random problems. If i were to use an if statement, what conditions should i use?

Answer (score 0):

That's a very weird question. If you're doing it for some practical purpose, and not as a puzzle I urge you to rethink your approach. Anyway, it's a nice little puzzle.

Here's one way you could do it - generate a random integer, then count the number of leading zeroes.

- There's a 1/2 chance of having zero leading zeroes (`1`)
- There's a 1/4 chance of having 1 leading zeroes (`01`)
- There's a 1/8 chance of having 2 leading zeroes (`001`)
- There's a 1/16 chance of having 3 leading zeroes (`0001`)
- There's a 1/32 chance of having 4 leading zeroes (`00001`)
- There's a 1/64 chance of having 5 leading zeroes (`000001`)
- etc

You could then `switch` on this number.

Of course there's a chance you'll get a number you don't have a case for (like 32). In that case, you'd probably need generate a new number and try again.